# Time difference in minutes

Tags: mysql, database

I am trying to calculate the remaining minutes to 00:00 am.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE midnightCountdown()
BEGIN
SELECT TIME_FORMAT(TIMEDIFF('24:00:00', CURRENT_TIME()),'%i');
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

But it gives the remaining minutes to the next whole hour:

> TIME_FORMAT(TIMEDIFF('24:00:00', CURRENT_TIME()),'%i')
>
> 16

I checked the current time in my WAMP program and it was correct, same as the system time.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why you are using TIME_FORMAT?

Just try this: `SELECT TIMEDIFF('24:00:00', CURRENT_TIME());`

Comment: @AliAdlavaran If I use that, it will show me the remaining hour, minutes and seconds. What I am trying to do is to calculate the remaning time in minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your approach you are ignoring the hours from `TIMEDIFF`. So you would need to extract the hours and multiply them by 60 and then add the value to the extractet minutes:

```
SELECT TIME_FORMAT(TIMEDIFF('24:00:00', CURRENT_TIME()),'%i')
     + TIME_FORMAT(TIMEDIFF('24:00:00', CURRENT_TIME()),'%H') * 60;
```

Another approach would be to convert the TIME_DIFF to seconds and divide it (integer division) by 60:

```
SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF('24:00:00', CURRENT_TIME())) DIV 60;
```

Note: In both cases you will get the number of **full** minutes. That means that at `23:59:30` the result will be `0`.

Comment: Oh, of course!! I understand it now, and it works fine! Thank you Paul.